# Use multiple variables in select

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I have a question about using variables.
I need to get different values from the same condition.
Is the following example correct?
Many thanks!!!!

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @var2 varchar(50)
SELECT @var1, @var2
FROM table
WHERE IF condicion1 IN (1, 2, 3)
BEGIN 
    SET @var1='Value1'
    SET @var2='Value2'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign values to variables in SELECT statement.

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(50)
DECLARE @var2 varchar(50)

SELECT @var1 = CASE WHEN condicion1 = 1 THEN 'Value1' 
                    WHEN condicion1 = 2 THEN 'Value1' 
                    WHEN condicion1 = 3 THEN 'Value1' END,
       @var2 = CASE WHEN condicion1 = 1 THEN 'Value2' 
                    WHEN condicion1 = 2 THEN 'Value2' 
                    WHEN condicion1 = 3 THEN 'Value2' END

FROM table
```